# ember js component observer does not work

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observers

I have a scenario in emberjs component where the observe does not get hit. I figured out the reason as 
"the component is not yet inserted when the component property being observed is set."

My questions is, couldn this be handled in a better way in ember js?

Better explanation can be found in the below jsbin`s.

[Not working Scenario](http://jsbin.com/tusile/1/edit?html,js,output)

[Working scenario](http://jsbin.com/kigegu/4/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? In this scenario, both observer functions would be better served as a computed property (via `Ember.Computed`).

Comment: Agreed, observers are overkill in both situations

Comment: Like i have mentioned in the comments, this was an example and not the actual use case. The actual use case being a huge one i thought of simplyfying it.
Basically there is a lot of calculation in the observer and its not just assigning it to another property
Also when you say
" both observer functions would be better served as a computed property "
if you use computed property in component it wont work owing to the same reason why the observer is not working

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is, why am I computing something, that isn't going to be used.  If it's going to be used, why am I not using a computed property?

Comment: @Kingpin2k
may be i didn get your point the right way but i feel i didn explain well either.
The example stated is just an example and not the actual use case i am ending up with!
I am computing something that is being used but i am computing more than one.
Since i am computing more than one i felt its better to use observers than computed properties!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify `.on('init')` to force the observers to run right after initialization; otherwise like @Kingpin2k mentioned - they don't run

```
App.TextboxDisplayComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  displayText: '',        

  boundProperty: '',

  observeBoundProperty: function () {
    this.set('displayText', this.get('boundProperty'));        
  }.observes('boundProperty').on('init')
});
```

Your (non-)working example [here](http://jsbin.com/muxapo/1/edit)

Comment: exactly what i wanted thank you
When i tried this i thought the observer will get hit only "on('init')" and wont get hit when the usual changes happens. Now i tested it and it happens even when there is a change

Comment: However i just realised why i didn use this concept earlier as well, there is a catch with this!
observeBoundProperty would get exectued on init even if boundProperty is not changed. If i wanted observer to get hit only on change then it wont be of much help : )
But nevertheless i could have a condition check inside it and most importantly its a much more cleaner version!